# Error occurs in using If statement in my TableAdapter

Tags: c#, vb.net, vb.net-to-c#

I'm currently working with VB.NET on my previous projects. Now, switching to C# from VB.NET. I tried an online converter but it doesn't seem work. I get the following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type int to bool.

Here is my code:

```c#
String verify = txtVerify.Text;

if (tblStudentTableAdapter.FillByVerifyStudent(dbInfoDataSet.tblStudent, verify, verify, verify))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Matched");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("No Result");
}
```

In VB.NET, there's no problem with it. Please give me an idea on how to solve this problem. Thank you in advance

Code in VB.NET:

```vb
Dim verify as String = txtVerify.Text;

if tblStudentTableAdapter.FillByVerifyStudent(dbInfoDataSet.tblStudent, verify, verify, verify) Then
    MessageBox.Show("Matched");
else
    MessageBox.Show("No Result");
End If
```

Comment: What doesn't work? What error message do you get?

Comment: If you had `Option Strict On` in your VB projects, as you should, then that code wouldn't have compiled there either. That `FillByVerifyStudent` method returns an `Int32`, not a `Boolean`, so it cannot be the condition for an `If` statement without a narrowing conversion, which C# won't do implicitly and VB will only do with `Option Strict Off`. Test the condition that you actually need tested.

Comment: The error is - cannot implicitly convert type int to bool

Comment: @Joa.know Well jmcilhinney's comment should answer your question then.

Comment: This code could never have worked in C# either.

Comment: @DavidG, that's what the question is about. It did work in VB but only because `Option Strict` was `Off`, thus allowing implicit narrowing conversions. The question is why the equivalent code doesn't work in C# and the reason is the same as why the same code doesn't work in VB with `Option Strict On`.

Comment: How I'm going to fix it @jmcilhinney. I'm stock on this! Thank you

Comment: I try to catch using If condition to search if the record is already exist. Then the message will show, any code you recommend?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `Convert.ToBoolean(int)` method to convert `int` to `bool`. This method will return `true` if the value of `int` is not zero.

```cs
String verify = txtVerify.Text;

if (Convert.ToBoolean(tblStudentTableAdapter.FillByVerifyStudent(dbInfoDataSet.tblStudent, verify, verify, verify)))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Matched");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("No Result");
}
```

Comment: Using `Convert.ToBoolean` is horrid, just add `== 1` on the end instead.

Comment: It worked! Actually I try many times using Convert Boolean but I putted in a wrong side. Anyway, Thank you very much

Comment: I would also suggest against using `Convert.ToBoolean` in this case. The proper way to approach this is to think about what the value returned by the `FillByVerifyStudent` actually means. Like an `Fill...` method on a table adapter, it simply calls `Fill` on a data adapter and returns the result and that result is the number of records retrieved by the query. In this specific instance, if the query retrieves no records then there is no match and the method returns 0, otherwise it returns a number greater than zero. THAT is what you should be testing for, i.e. `if (… > 0 )`.